# How to Move File and Rename it in C#, after receiving it from the server?

Tags: c#, move, file-rename

I am trying to move&rename a file which i received from my TCPserver.

My code for moving and renaming:

```
 *//My sourcePath*
 static string myServerfile = @"C:\Users\me\Documents\file_client\bin\Debug\test1.txt";
 *//My destinationPath*
 static string myFile = @"C:\test\inbox\JobStart.txt";
```

After receiving the file I do this:

```
          fs.Close ();
          serverStream.Close ();
                File.Move(myServerfile, myFile);
                Console.WriteLine("Moved");
            } 
            catch (Exception ex) 
            {
                Console.WriteLine ("Cannot be DONE!");  
            }
```

But it allways throws exception "Cannot be done" when it reaches `File.Move(myServerfile, myfile1);`

I tried this:
`Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());`

Result:
*System.IO.IOException: A file that already exists, can not be created.*

[image]

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: What's the actual exception in 'ex'? That will tell you why the move failed. It might be a permissioning issue, as you're moving a file from your user area to somewhere where access might be restricted.

Comment: Add a `Console.WriteLine (ex.ToString());` in the `catch` and tell us what that produces.

Comment: @Baldrik is right, show us the real error message.  Are those local paths on each machine?  If you are trying to access the c drive of the server from the client, you'll need a network path, not a local one.

Comment: Getting the file from server isn't a problem. The file is on my local harddrive @"C:\" I am trying to move file from one folder to another.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Seems like you already have had JobStart.txt file in the destination folder.

You may try to check whether it exists and then try to [replace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9d9h163f.aspx) or delete that file and then move.

```
if (File.Exists(myFile))
{
    File.Delete(myFile);
}
File.Move(myServerfile, myFile);
```

Comment: @RamHS - Please remember for the future, that the problem could only be solved after the exact exception message was known, So whenever you have a similar problem, be sure to include that information. Also, you might have realized, that a generic "doesn't work" message that hides the actual exception message is more harmful then helpful. The user of course doesn't want to see that "ugly" wall of text, but for you as a developer, that information is most valuable, so don't hide it from yourself. ^_^

Comment: @Corak Thanks for your advice. Yes it is a mistake that I did not do it but you learn only by making mistakes. I'll take your advice with me in the future. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
File.Move(@"C:\SAM.txt", @"C:\New Folder\SAM_newName.txt");
```

If successful, the first file will no longer exist. If unsuccessful, the operation will be terminated—nothing will be changed on disk. I recommend using this with a try, catch.